# How System.out.println() works

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

I checked the System class, there i saw:

```
public static final PrintStream out = null;
```

So, why doesn't System.out.println() result in nullPointerException because out is not pointing to any object ?  I have tried to find code in the System class that reassigns out to an PrintStream instance but i cannot find any code that does that...

please provide me the code line in the System class that reassigns the out variable...

Comment: There is a `setOut` method in that class - try putting a breakpoint in that method and see what is calling it.  (Probably early in the JVM startup.)

Comment: "_please provide me the code line in the System class that reassigns the out variable..._" -- Both duplicates have answers that tell you which methods are involved in setting `System.out`. You can find these methods in [System.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java). There are also answers explaining how native code can bypass the `final` keyword. You can find the native method implementations in [System.c](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/System.c).

Comment: For instance, [System::setOut](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L259) calls the method [System::setOut0](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L348) which calls [this native method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/System.c#L272).